# ruby exit tail and continue to next part of script from keypress

Tags: ruby, loops, ssh, tail

I found this snippet of code I am having trouble trying to find a good way to exit the tail and move on to the next part of the script. Essentially I ant the first part to make a change for the person running the scripts, show log output using the below code, then move on to the next part of the script on user keypress. I cant get out of the tail without CTRL-C.

```
def do_tail( session, file )
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
      puts "[#{file}] -> #{data}"
    end
    channel.exec "tail -f #{file}"
  end
end

Net::SSH.start("server", "user", :keys => ["/user/.ssh/id_dsa"]) do |session|
  do_tail session, "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
  do_tail session, "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
  session.loop
end
```

**UPDATE**
The -f takes over I/O and makes it difficult to exit that ssh channel. I decided to move towards the suggestions and modify it. Here is the result in case someone else would like help on this topic.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

def exit?
        begin
                while input = STDIN.read_nonblock(1)
                return true if input == 'q'
                end
                false
                rescue Errno::EINTR
                false
                rescue Errno::EAGAIN
                false
                rescue EOFError
                true
        end
end

def do_tail( session, file )
        session.open_channel do |channel|
                channel.on_data do |ch, data|
                        puts "[#{file}]\n\n#{data}"
                end
                channel.exec "tail -n22 #{file}"
        end
end

def loggy
        iteration = 0
        loop do
                iteration = (iteration + 1)
                Net::SSH.start("server", "user", :keys => ["/user/.ssh/id_dsa"]) do |session|
                        do_tail session, "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
                end
                puts "\n\nType 'q' and <ENTER> to exit log stream when you are done!\n\n"
                sleep 5
        break if exit? or iteration == 3
        end
end

loggy

loop do
        puts "\nDo you need to view more of the log? (y/n)\n"
        confirm = gets.chomp
        if confirm =="y"
                loggy
        else
        end
        break if confirm == "n"
end
puts "Part Deaux!"
```

Comment: Note that you aren't passing any parameters to the `do_tail` function that would let it run `tail` on only a portion of the file; is the question "Do you need to view more of the log?" intended in the spirit of "View further back in the log" or in the spirit of "see the last 22 lines of the log file just in case they've changed" ?

Comment: Perhaps the thing to do is take a little further step back and describe what you're trying to accomplish; what's this script helping you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given the `-f` command line option to `tail(1)`. That explicitly instructs `tail(1)` to exit when the user types `^C` or otherwise kills the program. If you just want a specific amount of the file to be shown and *not* followed, then you might wish to use the `-n` command line option instead:

```
channel.exec "tail -n 24 #{file}"
```

`24` will show roughly one terminal's worth of data, though if your terminals are larger or smaller -- or you're interested in different amounts of data -- then you might wish to tweak it further.

`tail(1)` is powerful; it'd be worth reading its documentation just in case there's an even better way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I realize that -f is the real culprit in making this complicated. Unfortunately it is necessary. I did almost add a huge ammount of complication by starting a loop and outputting the newest lines in batches. I think my solution is going to involve grabbing the pid of the tail and sending a kill through the channel to that pid to exit the tail. That way it can run until the user intervenes by pressing "q" and I'll just figure out a loop on STDIN looking for a "q" then trigger the kill, and move on with the rest of the script. Unless someone has a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use `less` instead of tail. Try this:

```
less +F filename; echo 'after less'
```

When you hit ctrl+c, q in less it will quit and then echo what you want.